# Table view with different custom cells

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a view controller with a table view, designed in a storyboard, this table view uses three different custom cells, each one for three different sections. I have defined each custom cell as a prototype cell, using a different identifier for every one, and a custom cell object defined in every cell in Xcode, linked by Interface Builder with every control of every cell.

I have put custom cells as section order, you can see it here. Every marked square is a custom prototype cell.

[image]

And here is the table view code:

```
  - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    return 3;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (indexPath.section==2){
            return 40;
        }else if (indexPath.section==1){
            return 40;
        } else if (indexPath.section==0){
            return 205;

        }

}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section==0){
        return 1;
    } else if (section==1){
        return [[selectedTeam valueForKey:@"jugadores"]count];
    } else if (section==2){
        return [[selectedTeam valueForKey:@"tecnicos"]count];
    }

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)table cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (indexPath.section==0){

        NSString *imageService = @"http://backend.exular.net/contenido/";


        imageCell *cellImage = [table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"imatge"];

        if (cellImage == nil) {
            cellImage = [[imageCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone reuseIdentifier:@"imatge"];
        }

        cellImage.leagueName.text = [selectedTeam valueForKey:@"nom"];

        NSString *path= [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@" ,imageService,  [selectedTeam valueForKey:@"img"]] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];

        [cellImage.teamPicture  setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

        imageService=nil;

        return cellImage;

    } else if (indexPath.section==1){


         teamCell *cellTeam = [table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"equipo"];

         if (cellTeam == nil) {
             cellTeam = [[teamCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone reuseIdentifier:@"equipo"];
         }

         NSDictionary *teamDic =  [[selectedTeam valueForKey:@"jugadores"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

         cellTeam.name.text = [teamDic valueForKey:@"nom"];

         cellTeam.height.text = [teamDic valueForKey:@"height"];

         cellTeam.number.text = [teamDic valueForKey:@"altura"];

         cellTeam.date.text = [teamDic valueForKey:@"date"];

         cellTeam.position.text = [teamDic valueForKey:@"posicion"];

         return cellTeam;

    } else if (indexPath.section==2){

        NSString *CellIdentifier = @"staff";

        staffCell *cellStaff = [table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"staff"];

        if (cellStaff == nil) {
            cellStaff = [[staffCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone reuseIdentifier:@"staff"];
        }

        NSDictionary *staffDic = [[selectedTeam valueForKey:@"tecnicos"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cellStaff.name.text = [staffDic valueForKey:@"nom"];

        cellStaff.role.text = [staffDic valueForKey:@"posicion"];

        return cellStaff;

    }

    return nil;
}
```

Xcode gaves me this error :`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<teamCell 0x8d4f6b0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key role.'` and the execution breaks at line

```
teamCell *cellTeam = [table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"equipo"];
```

I will appreciate your help.

Many thanks.

Comment: In the `numberOfSectionsInTableView` it returns 2, but seems there are at least 3, and `} else if (indexPath.section==3){` indicates there might be 4.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I searching which is the first index for sections, I don't know if I need 3 sections, I must set return 3 and begin the iteration using index 1? Many thanks!!!

Comment: Section index starts at 0.  If you have 3 sections, the sections indices will be 0, 1, and 2.

Comment: I have updated attached code, with modifications I still have the same error, it seems that is not getting prototype cells...Many thanks. I seems that despite in section 1, I want to use teamCell, is trying to access role key, that belongs to staffCell, and is set in section 2 as you can see in code.

Comment: Check to make sure that you have the correct cell identifiers set in IB for your teamCell and staffCell.

Comment: It was an issue related to IB, a control had a wrong link set. Many thanks to all for your help. rdelmar please enter your answer in order to vote it.